# flutter web vercel deployment throws 404 error

Tags: flutter-web, vercel

I am getting a 404 error from my vercel deployment of flutter web project. The error has a link which redirects me to this [url](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/edge-network/frequently-asked-questions#why-do-i-see-a-404-error-when-accessing-my-deployment).

I get the error when I try to access a route `www.foobar.com/post/123456`.

I am using [go router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) for my project. And the build command is as follows:

```
flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit --dart-define=BROWSER_IMAGE_DECODING_ENABLED=false --release
```

Most of the flags in the build command is necessary for my project. What might be the issue and how to solve it?

The initial route which is "/" loads without any issue. The problem only happens when I try to navigate to any other route

Comment: I don't know much about flutter web projects, but if it's like a single page app then you'll need to configure rewrites in vercel config to return the index.html for all urls: `"rewrites": [{"source": "/:a*", "destination": "/"}]`

Comment: that did it. thanks. had to add a vercel.json

Comment: Do you mind if I write that as an answer so you can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For single page apps you'll have to return the index.html for all URLs.

You can do this by [configuring rewrites](https://vercel.com/docs/project-configuration#project-configuration/rewrites) in your vercel.json config.

Here's how it looks like in my vercel.json for example:

```json
{
  "version": 2,
  "name": "myappname",
  "rewrites": [
    // rewrite all URLs to "/" which will serve the index.html
    // if you have more rewrites then put them above this one
    {"source": "/:a*", "destination": "/"}
  ]
}
```